Можно ли вставить один параметр в другой параметр функции на php?
Возможно ли вставить один параметр в другой параметр функции в php или стоит искать другое решение?
Предположим у нас есть вот такой скрипт.
//Есть переменная шаблона, и в нужное место нужно вставить имя, которое в дальнейшем получается при выгрузки из БД
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy'.$name.' ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.';    
....
//Выгрузили из БД и добавили в переменную
$name = 'Tom'; 

И есть функция в которую эти параметры передаются переменная-шаблон и имя выгруженное из бд
function func1($template, $n){
// Нужно вывести шаблон с подставленным именем
return $template
}

echo func1($text, $name);

Получается, что передаём в функцию 1 аргументом шаблон, вторым имя, которое выгрузили из БД и нам нужно это как то соединить, не знаю как это реализовать, если менять местами нельзя, по алгоритму с кучей проверок именно такая последовательность идет... Подскажите как поступить?

В общем, пока ждал ответ на вопрос придумал такое решение....
//Вместо просто переменной создал функцию возвращающую шаблон
finction template($name){
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy '.$name.' text of the printing and typesetting industry.';
return $text;    
}

//Выгрузили из БД и добавили в переменную
$name = 'Tom'; 

// Функция, которая принимает шаблон и имя
function func1($template) {
    return $template
}

//Вызов функции
echo func1(template($name));

Такое решение нормальное или всё-таки лучше через реплейс?

// Функция, возвращающая шаблон с подставленным именем
function template($name) {
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy ' . $name . ' text of the printing and typesetting industry.';
return $text;
}
// Выгрузили из БД и добавили в переменную
$name = 'Tom';
// Функция, которая принимает шаблон и возвращает его
function func1($template) {
return $template; // Возвращаем переданный шаблон
}
// Вызов функции и вывод результата
echo func1(template($name));

Так тоже будет работать.

По времени отработаки:
Ваша функция = Execution time: 0.000122s
Функция с str_replace = Execution time: 0.000250s
Вот чистая математика)) Получается в 2 раза быстрее отработает.

Спасибо) Разобрались)
